# SQL Server - add/cumulative for last 3 days

Tags: sql-server

Table 1

Amount

```
10
20
25
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
110
120
130
```

Write an sql query to get output as

```
    07/11/2018  10  
    07/12/2018  20  
    07/13/2018  25  55
    07/14/2018  40  85
    07/15/2018  50  115
    07/16/2018  60  150
    07/17/2018  70  180
    07/18/2018  80  210
    07/19/2018  90  240
    07/20/2018  100 270
    07/21/2018  110 300
    07/22/2018  120 330
    07/23/2018  130 360
```

So I want to add the last 3 days amount values and get the sum.

Comment: Before any of us (**volunteers**) complete your request, what you have you tried so far? If you're having problems, what if you question? (Stack overflow isn't a free coding service).

Comment: should your input have dates attached to the rows?

Comment: yes, the dates are also there in table

Comment: @Cato HA!!! how did I not even notice the sample data was lacking a date... /facepalm.

Comment: @user1254053 then, when you add what your tried, please also add sample data that is representative of your actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LAG window function is what you need. It allows you to access the value in a column from a previous row. The format is LAG([Column], [Row Offset], [Default]), so this example adds the value from the current row to the value 2 rows back and the value 1 row back.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (dt DATE, c INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('07/11/2018',10),
('07/12/2018',20),
('07/13/2018',25),
('07/14/2018',40),
('07/15/2018',50),
('07/16/2018',60),
('07/17/2018',70),
('07/18/2018',80),
('07/19/2018',90),
('07/20/2018',100),
('07/21/2018',110),
('07/22/2018',120),
('07/23/2018',130)

SELECT dt, c, 
    c + LAG(c, 2) OVER (ORDER BY dt) + LAG(c, 1) OVER (ORDER BY dt)
FROM @t
ORDER BY dt
```

Returns:

```
dt          c   
2018-07-11  10  NULL
2018-07-12  20  NULL
2018-07-13  25  55
2018-07-14  40  85
2018-07-15  50  115
2018-07-16  60  150
2018-07-17  70  180
2018-07-18  80  210
2018-07-19  90  240
2018-07-20  100 270
2018-07-21  110 300
2018-07-22  120 330
2018-07-23  130 360
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you a full answer here, as you've not responded to my comments. Thus I'm going to give you a partial answer, so that you can work out how to do this yourself.

When working with `SUM`, you also have access to the `OVER` clause. In 2012+ (which I assume you're using, as 2008 is effectively out of support now, and anything before is completely unsupported) you have access to the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause in `OVER`.

For example:

```
WITH N AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) V(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2)
SELECT I,
       SUM(I) OVER (ORDER BY I
                    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS SomeSum
FROM Tally
ORDER BY I;
```

This example calculates the `SUM` of the current row, and the 3 following rows afterwards. So, for `I = 1`, that's `SUM(1,2,3,4) = 10`.

This can all be found in the documentation: [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)